# capistrano error concerning cap production deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ubuntu, github, capistrano

Has anyone seen this error with Capistrano when running the "cap production deploy" command from my dev machine.

```
00:05 git:clone
      The repository mirror is at /home/deploy/myapp/repo
00:05 git:update
      01 git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/myapp.git
      01 fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '/home/deploy/myapp/repo'
      01 To add an exception for this directory, call:
      01
      01    git config --global --add safe.directory /home/deploy/myapp/repo
```

I added the exception on my dev machine, but it still gave me the same error message.

Comment: Make sure both parent of .git and .git folders are owned by exact user you run git from. If you don't want to make directory ownerships consistent, follow the hint in the error message.

Comment: Thank you, I am still a newbie with Mac (dev machine) and Ubuntu (prod server).
What commands could I type to check on this further?

Comment: @273k thanks, but adding "git config --global --add safe.directory /home/deploy/myapp/repo" to my dev machine, didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command on prod server

sudo chown -R deploy:deploy /home/deploy/myapp